# Geoserver SLD TextSymbolizer showing up

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, sld, xml

I am very new to geoserver and SLD.

I am trying to put labels on my heatmap layer using SLD but the labels are not showing up in the preview. I found this example to implement it which looked straight forward yet it is not showing up.

[Developing a Web Map Server Using GeoServer](http://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Developing_a_Web_Map_Server_Using_GeoServer)

I have been searching online and i haven't seen anything to help me troubleshoot this problem.

Here is my SLD:

```
<Rule>
        <RasterSymbolizer>
        <!-- specify geometry attribute to pass validation -->
          <Geometry>
            <ogc:PropertyName>wkb_geometry</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
          <Opacity>0.6</Opacity>
          <ColorMap type="ramp" >
            <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0" 
              opacity="0"/>
            <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0.02" label="nodata"
              opacity="0"/>
            <ColorMapEntry color="#4444FF" quantity=".1" label="nodata"/>
            <ColorMapEntry color="#FF0000" quantity=".5" label="values" />
            <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="1.0" label="values" />
          </ColorMap>
        </RasterSymbolizer>
        <TextSymbolizer>
            <label>
                <ogc:PropertyName>aqi</ogc:PropertyName>
          </label>
       </TextSymbolizer>
       </Rule>
```

Here is a screenshot of the layer attributes:

[image]

Comment: First of all, I think you need a WPS extention, if not already installed?  
see discussion [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Boundless-Heatmap-demo-Unable-to-find-function-gs-Heatmap-td5095164.html).  
  Also, this is a good [guide](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.x/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation)

Comment: Yes WPS is already installed and heatmap is generating. However I wanted to put labels on the heatmap with the TextSymbolizer using the aqi values but labels are not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to apply the `textSymbolizer` to the raster output rather than the underlying layer. I would move the labeling to a separate rule:

```
 <Rule>
    <RasterSymbolizer>
    <!-- specify geometry attribute to pass validation -->
      <Geometry>
        <ogc:PropertyName>wkb_geometry</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
      <Opacity>0.6</Opacity>
      <ColorMap type="ramp" >
        <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0" 
          opacity="0"/>
        <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" quantity="0.02" label="nodata"
          opacity="0"/>
        <ColorMapEntry color="#4444FF" quantity=".1" label="nodata"/>
        <ColorMapEntry color="#FF0000" quantity=".5" label="values" />
        <ColorMapEntry color="#FFFF00" quantity="1.0" label="values" />
      </ColorMap>
    </RasterSymbolizer>
  </Rule>
  <Rule>
    <TextSymbolizer>
        <label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>aqi</ogc:PropertyName>
      </label>
   </TextSymbolizer>
   </Rule>
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. It is still just showing the heatmap without labels.

Comment: You must match the attribute name exactly - so in your case AQI not aqi